# Is it possible for a child in a grid-area to overlap on another grid-area?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

There is a "sidenav" grid-area (list of menus) and there is a "content" grid-area to the right side of sidenav. On clicking one of the menu items in sidenav grid-area, I want to show sub menus(li elements) on the right side of the parent menu overlapping the "content" grid area.

The following css is written and the sub menu doesn't show up. The entire setup works fine when CSS grids are not used. How to achieve the same using CSS grids?

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .main_container {
       grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 1fr;
       grid-template-areas: 
           "logo       header"
           "sidenav    content"
    }
}
```

Expected output:

[image: Please click here to see the expected output]

Comment: Think we're gonna need a **reduced case** demo here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use z-index, item with the higher number will overlap items with the lower number, example:

```
.grid > div:nth-child(2) {
z-index: 1; // this will be underneath items with higher z-index
}
.grid > div:nth-child(3) {
z-index: 2; // this will overlapp items with lower z-index
}
```

It is explained well here https://gridbyexample.com/learn/2016/12/20/learning-grid-day20/

Comment: Thanks Raitar. I missed that piece. It works fine.